# Thevenin equivalent voltage calculation

Tags: voltage, thevenin

Hi please see diagram attached. I can calculate the Rth but I am confused about the equivalent Vth. The part that makes this difficult for me to understand is the 2A current source. Could you please help and explain how Vth is calculated and it's of value 6V.
Thanks
[image]

Comment: Look up something called *focus*, then do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Emf source of 12V and the resistance of 6ohm can be converted to a current source of 2A in parellel with a resistance of 6ohm.

Both the 2A current sources are of same direction.

Hence the can be combined to a current source of 4A in oarallel with 6ohm.

Convert this 4A current source in parallel with 6ohm to an EMF source of 24V in series with 6ohm.

This entire set is in series in 6ohm, 4ohm.

The current in circuit is i = 24V/16ohm = 1.5Amp

The voltage acroos 4ohm is 4ohm * 1.5Amp = 6V.

Rth = Two 6ohm resistors in series and these two in parallel to the 4ohm resistors = 3ohm

Hence Vth = 6V and Rth = 3ohm.[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can apply Superposition Theorem

Effect of 12V = (12/(6+4+6)) x 4 = 3V [open ckt 2A current source]

Effect of 2A = 2 x (6/(6+4+6)) x 4 = 3V [short ckt 12V battery]

Vth=3+3= 6V

Comment: superposition theorem...always the all time favorite theorem :D